# Text escaping div on mobile screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a site where a lot of text will be displayed, when it is in normal screen size it works fine, but when I shrink the browser to mobile size the text escapes the div, as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMPH7.png

Here is the blade file:

```
<div class="flex justify-center ">
    <div class="w-11/12 bg-gray-400 p-6 rounded-lg font-serif text-4xl font-bold bg-opacity-70 subpixel-antialiased tracking-wide not-italic">
        <div class="p-10 shadow-2xl mb-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 border-solid border-2 border-black rounded-lg">
            <div class="bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-solid border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-lg">

                <h1 class="pt-2 pl-4 text-4xl font-bold text-gray-900 title-font mb-8 underline">
                    {{ $post->Titel }}
                </h1>

                <div class="flex-grow">
                    <div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Standort: {{ $post->Standort }}</div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Kontakt: {{ $post->Kontakt }}</div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Startdatum: {{ $post->startdate }}</div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif mb-8"> Enddatum: {{ $post->enddate }}</div>
                        <div class="flex-grow ml-5 ml-8 break-words mb-5 content w-full md:w-3/4 pr-4 text-lg text-justify tracking-widest leading-loose mr-7 subpixel-antialiased">
                            {!! $post->Beschreibung !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-start font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif mb-5 ml-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="text-white px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition
                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Direkt bewerben!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried it with break-words and break-all. Aswell trying to add a padding or margin.. but I am fairly new to css and I think it isn't the correct approach.

The div with the text in it is the one with `{!! $post->beschreibung !!}`

Comment: Please create a [mre] using the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` tag in your header?

Comment: hey @miken32 again! :D 

I don't think it is reproducable since it is linked to a database :/ I could paste the text here which is inputted, would that help?

Comment: @GillesBraun yes!

Comment: This is an HTML question, so server-side code is not relevant. View source and copy the HTML in question. You can use the snippet functionality to display the HTML live in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `w-full` css class. `w-full` will set the width to be 100% of the parent, which in combination with the `ml-5 ml-8` classes, will exceed the parent's size.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o93udj4v/